# How to sort files in the ascending order of integer contained in the file name

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list `a`. I want to arrange these files in ascending order like,

1. kernal_1.0.npy
2. kernal_10.npy
3. kernal_50.npy
4. kernal_100.npy

If I use split function it only splits extension npy. Sorted function only works fine on integers. What should I do for this purpose?

```
a = ['kernal_1.0.npy','kernal_100.npy','kernal_50.npy','kernal_10.npy' ]
b='kernal_1.0.npy'
print(os.path.splitext(b))
```

Comment: try    b[7:-4]     .........

Comment: yes but it is simple indexing. Can I sort the list a in ascending oder(w.r.t integer contained in file name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the beginning is always the same, as well as the end, you could make your search based on the index.

```
a = ['kernal_1.0.npy','kernal_100.npy','kernal_50.npy','kernal_10.npy' ]
prefix_len = len('kernal_')
prefix_ext = len('.npy')

# Here, the key parameter means *how* you want to sort your list. So, 
# basically, at each operation, it will sort based on this argument. The 
# lambda here is basically a function, on which I invite you to document 
# yourself on.
# This line says : Sort this list, and compare every elements using 
# only the letters between the prefix_len'th index and the prefix_ext index,
# casted as `float` numbers.
b = sorted(a, key = lambda x: float(x[prefix_len:-prefix_ext]) )

print(b)
# ['kernal_1.0.npy', 'kernal_10.npy', 'kernal_50.npy', 'kernal_100.npy']
```

### Probably more explicit explanation for you.

```
def show_list_based_on_lambda(arr, key):
    """ When you use the key parameter in a sorting function, it behaves
        the same way as here. Meaning at every iteration, it will
        only consider the elements returned by the function you sent in.
    """
    for elem in arr:
        print( key(elem) )


#   This function is supposed to strip off the first and last character of an iterable.
f = lambda x:x[1:-1]
arr = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee']
show_list_based_on_lambda(arr, f)
# a
# b
# c
# d
# e


#   This function is supposed to add one to every element that passes by.
f = lambda x:x+1
arr = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
show_list_based_on_lambda(arr, f)
# 11
# 21
# 31
# 41
# 51
```

Comment: Does lambda x considers whole list in every comparison? for sorting we mostly use a[6:-4] if a is only 'kernal_1.0.npy'.  Can I say that x is a list exactly like a but only considering integers. Beside is this function lamda x is playing a role of for loop for selecting integer values?

Comment: @jerry I updated my answer, I think this time it is very clear

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Pandas Series` to generalize the solution:

```
a = np.array(['kernal_1.0.npy','kernal_100.npy','kernal_50.npy','kernal_10.npy' ])
idx_ = pd.Series(a).str.split('.', expand=True).iloc[:, 0]\
        .str.split('_', expand=True).iloc[:, 1]\
        .astype(int).sort_values(0).index

a[idx_]
array(['kernal_1.0.npy', 'kernal_10.npy', 'kernal_50.npy',
       'kernal_100.npy'], dtype='<U14')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `os.path.splitext` with `str.split` in `sorted` or `list.sort`:

```
import os

a = ['kernal_1.0.npy','kernal_100.npy','kernal_50.npy','kernal_10.npy']

sorted(a, key = lambda x: float(os.path.splitext(x)[0].split('_')[1]))
# ['kernal_1.0.npy', 'kernal_10.npy', 'kernal_50.npy', 'kernal_100.npy']
```

Comment: What role is played by key=lambda. I came across this command but still confused about lambda

Comment: `key` specifies how `sorted` should do the sorting. In your case, its the `float`-like str in the middle of each element. `lambda x: ...` in the answer provide a function to extract necessary information. `lambda` in general is often used in such one-line answers as it can be unnecessarily long to define new function using `def`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following old and classic way of doing:

```
import re

def numeric_compare(x, y):
  u = re.findall("\d+(?:\.\d+)?", x)
  v = re.findall("\d+(?:\.\d+)?", y)
  u = [0] if len(u) == 0 else u
  v = [0] if len(v) == 0 else v
  return int(float(u[0]) - float(v[0]))

a = ['kernal_1.0.npy','kernal_100.npy','kernal_50.npy','kernal_10.npy' ]
print(a)
print(sorted(a, cmp=numeric_compare))
```

**Output:**

```
['kernal_1.0.npy', 'kernal_100.npy', 'kernal_50.npy', 'kernal_10.npy']
['kernal_1.0.npy', 'kernal_10.npy', 'kernal_50.npy', 'kernal_100.npy']
```

**Explanations:**

- You define your own sorting function `numeric_compare`
- You extract the real numbers from the string you are comparing
- If your string does not contain any number you set the value to `0`
- Then you compare both extracted floated and you cast it back to `int` as you need to have your function return an `int`
- You call `sorted()` on your list with your comparison function

This way of doing is robust and will also work on file where you do not have any number in them:

**input:**

```
b = ['kernal_1.0.npy','kernal_100.npy','kernal_50.npy','kernal_10.npy', 'abc' ]
```

**output:**

```
['abc', 'kernal_1.0.npy', 'kernal_10.npy', 'kernal_50.npy', 'kernal_100.npy']
```

If you prefer to have files that do not have numbers in them appearing at the end of the list instead of being sorted at the beginning then you can replace `u = [0]` and `v = [0]` by `u = [sys.maxsize]` and `v = [sys.maxsize]`. (you need to add `import sys` at the beginning of your code)

**Regex demo and explanations**:
    https://regex101.com/r/evIeVD/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
b = sorted(a, key = lambda x : int(x[x.find('_')+1:].split('.')[0]))
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
b = ['kernal_1.0.npy', 'kernal_10.npy', 'kernal_50.npy', 'kernal_100.npy']
```

Comment: What if the first element is `kernal_1.5.npy` and the second element `kernal_1.3.npy` ?

Comment: @IMCoins For that case, it would fail; as it is only taking the integer part after `_` and before first `.`